# Unable to generate a Bundle of CA Root Certificates (failed to create symbolic link)

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I am trying to generate a Bundle of CA Root Certificates. Similar to what Facebook has done for its PHP SDK (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt).

I tried to follow the example here: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/cacerts.html

The first command seemed to work.

First command:

```
certhost='http://mxr.mozilla.org'                        &&
certdir='/mozilla/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins' &&
url="$certhost$certdir/certdata.txt?raw=1"               &&

wget --output-document certdata.txt $url &&
unset certhost certdir url               &&
make-ca.sh                               &&
remove-expired-certs.sh certs
```

But the second one:

```
SSLDIR=/etc/ssl                                             &&
install -d ${SSLDIR}/certs                                  &&
cp -v certs/*.pem ${SSLDIR}/certs                           &&
c_rehash                                                    &&
install BLFS-ca-bundle*.crt ${SSLDIR}/ca-bundle.crt         &&
ln -sv ../ca-bundle.crt ${SSLDIR}/certs/ca-certificates.crt &&
unset SSLDIR
```

I got this error at the end:

```
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate Verisign_Class_1_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority.pem
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate Verisign_Class_1_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority.pem
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt': File exists
```

I got a lot of WARNINGs... The problem is that I am unsure if it is a good idea to share them here in the public and also they are so many of them.

I am new to all of this. So what am I doing wrong and also is there a easier way?

I am on Ubuntu. Using OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012.

- Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
- Description:  Ubuntu 12.10
- Release:  12.10
- Codename: quantal

My SSL CA provider is Godaddy.